# Android:How can i change the color of the text of the ListAdapter?

Tags: android

The default color of the text is white. Let's say if i want to change the color, then how can i do it? Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommened writing your own theme for the list view and then setting it in the layouts xml file, this means that you can use the same style throughout your app

This is a good tutorial to start with
http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/

Answer (score 1):

in the getView method, find your TextView and  set the color via setTextColor().
If you want your color changed for you based on the state of the item ( selected/focused etc) create new color in my_color.xml and define your states - examples of stateful colors are in SDK in res folders.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is use your own layout for the list items. This way you could set whatever color or any other layout in the items.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't use setTextColor(); in your ListAdapter ? I think you could